# Change Event.. not working on multple select

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is what my HTML looks like, I am using while to loop them. Not the main problem.

```
 <select id='stat'>

    <option selected='selected' disabled></option> 
    <option value=Paid>Paid</option>
    <option value=UnPaid>UnPaid</option>
    </select>
    </td>   
</tr>
</select>


<select id='stat'>

    <option selected='selected' disabled></option> 
    <option value=Paid>Paid</option>
    <option value=UnPaid>UnPaid</option>
    </select>
    </td>   
</tr>
</select>
```

This is my ajax/jquery, my code works on the first **Select** but on the next select and so on.. change event does not work anymore. It only works on my first select.

```
$(function () {
    $('select#stat').change(function () {
        var xz = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../post.php',
            data: {
                x: 'x',
                idx: xz,
                status: $('select#stat').val()
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('Status Changed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An id should be unique, therefore you can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Instead, use class.

In the HTML

```
<select class="stat"></select>
```

And to reference it in the javascript file, use

```
$(".stat").on("change", function() {});
```

Here is a JSFiddle with your code working:

http://jsfiddle.net/2xr3r/

Comment: its still not changing the other select. it only changes still the first select

Comment: Did you change $(".stat").change(function.. to $(".stat").on("change", function.. ?

Comment: yes.. I did, but it's still, other select are still not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Did you change the selector in the status property too?

Answer (score 0):

Taking Stefan's answer further, you can use `event.target` to trace the caller like so:

```
$(".stat").on("change", function(e) {
    if(e.target.id == 'one') {
        // logic for select with id 1 here
        alert('one');
    } else {
         // logic for select with id 2 here
        alert('two');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="stat" id="one">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<select class="stat" id="two">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r5ZsL/1/